# Add props to component in setup() method / ionic & vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ionic-framework

I'm trying to pass props to a component in `<ion-nav>`.
For this `<ion-nav>` I followed this tutorial:
https://aaronksaunders.hashnode.dev/how-to-navigate-in-ionic-modals-with-ion-nav-in-vuejs

My code currently looks like this:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <ion-nav :root="orderUpdate" id="modal-nav"></ion-nav>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { defineComponent } from "vue";
import { IonNav } from "@ionic/vue";
import OrderUpdate from "@/components/OrderUpdate";

export default defineComponent({
  name: "OrderUpdateModal",
  components: {
    IonNav
  },
  setup(){

      const orderUpdate = OrderUpdate
      return {
          orderUpdate
      }
  },
  created() {
      console.log(this.positions);
  },
  props: {
    order: [],
    positions: [],
    materials: [],
  },
});
</script>
```

As you can see I use the component `OrderUpdate` in the `setup()` function.
Sadly I've got no idea how I can pass my props  to this component. I've tried the following but this obviously doesn't work:

`<ion-nav :positions="positions" :materials="materials" :order="order" :root="orderUpdate" id="modal-nav"></ion-nav>`

Does someone have an Idea how I can achieve this?

Comment: I suppose you can try to pass in a slot to this 'wrapper' component with the props already applied. You can then access the slot contents programmatically with `$slots.default`. I don't know this framework so I don't know if there is a better way, but this would probably work.

Comment: Sounds promising. Can you make an answer with an example so I can try it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass options to the component using the [`rootParams` property](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/nav) in the template:

```html
<template>
  <ion-nav :root="OrderUpdate" :rootParams="rootParams" />
</template>

<script>
import OrderUpdate from '@/components/OrderUpdate.vue'

export default {
  setup() {
    return {
      OrderUpdate,
      rootParams: {
        positions: 'my positions',
        materials: 'my materials',
        order: 'my order',
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Alternatively, you can do this programmatically:

```html
<template>
  <ion-nav ref="ionNav" />
</template>

<script>
import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue'
import OrderUpdate from '@/components/OrderUpdate.vue'

export default {
  setup() {
    const ionNav = ref(null)

    const pushOrderUpdate = () => {
      ionNav.value.push(OrderUpdate, {
        positions: 'my positions',
        materials: 'my materials',
        order: 'my order',
      })
    }

    onMounted(() => pushOrderUpdate())

    return {
      ionNav,
    }
  }
}
</script>
```